# Dynamically set connection string of SSIS package through cmd

Tags: ssis, cmd

I am trying to dynamically set the connection string of my SSIS package through DTEXEC.exe

My CMD file consists of following command.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.exe" /f     
"D:\ABC\XYZ\Packages\ABCD.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING V /CONSOLELOG/Conn    
"Configurations;'"Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYY;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated    
Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;'"" /SET    
"\Package.Variables[User::TargetEnvironmentId].Properties[Value]";"2"
```

If i take out connection string part it works fine but when i add

```
/Conn "Configurations;'"Data Source=XXXXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYY;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;
Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;'""
```

This it throws exception and says INVALID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the name of your connection manager called "Configurations"? I can only assume that is the case. Give the following a try:

`/CONNECTION "Configurations";"\"Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=YYYY;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;\""`

I always find it easier to use DTExecUI to create the script, have you tried doing that?

Either that or set the connection string as a variable and pass that through DTExec